Inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{-as}/s^2$ for $a>0$
I am trying to compute the inverse Laplace transform of $$F(s) = \frac{e^{-as}}{s^2}$$ for $a > 0$.
I computed it as follows:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to t} \left\{\frac{e^{-as}}{s^2}\right\} = \text{Res}_{s=0}\left\{\frac{e^{-as}}{s^2}e^{st}\right\} = \lim_{s\to 0}\frac{d}{ds}e^{(t-a)s} = t-a$$
However the answer should be $$(t-a)H(t-a)$$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. I am confused as to how to produce this factor of $H$ when performing the computation (I assume it has something to do with guaranteeing convergence?). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$\int_a^{\infty}e^{-sx}(x-a)dx=e^{-as}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sy}ydy=\frac{e^{-as}}{s^2}.$$ You have the perfect answer.

But $t-a$ is not correct since the Laplace transform is defined on $[0,\infty]$, so you need the Heaviside factor to change the interval of integration to $[a,\infty]$. My question is how do I generate this Heaviside factor.
